# DataTable Rowstate always in Added state

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have these line of codes

```
DataTable DTable = new DataTable();
DTable.Columns.Add("Domain");
DTable.Rows.Add("Sample");
DTable.AcceptChanges();
DGridView.DataSource = DomainTable;
```

And this button for saving the changes

```
private void SaveDChangesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           foreach(DataRow dr in Dtable.Rows)
           {
               if(dr.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
               {

               }
           }
        }
```

My problem is that even though I modified the first row, the `Rowstate` always return **Added**.

Comment: @TanmayNehete Good article but doesn't answer my question

Comment: How did you modify(edit) the DataGridView? And can you show more code of above one? Basically, editing values on DataGridView doesn't make the changes same to the DataTable inside DataGridView.

Comment: I modify it when running in VS in runtime

Comment: modify on where? on DataGridView?

Comment: The datatable is inside the DataGridView

Answer (score 0):

[RowState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a flags enumeration and **more than one value** can be on.

Always use the `HasFlag` function to test for a value! So change this:

```
   if(dr.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
   {
         // do the saving stuff
   }
```

for this:

```
   if(dr.RowState.HasFlag(DataRowState.Modified) )
   {
         // do the saving stuff
   }
```

Do note that both for `Added` and `Modified` to be on `AcceptChanges` must not have been called..:

> Added :  The row has been added to a DataRowCollection, and
>   AcceptChanges has not been called
>
> Modified : The row has been modified and AcceptChanges has not been
>   called.

If you add a row and let the user modify it (or do it in code) then **both** flags should be **on** and the original condition in your code is **false** despite the fact the has in fact been modified!

But **if** you **have** called [`AcceptChanges`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.acceptchanges%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the rows or the whole table as your code suggests then **neither** flag is on!