# The given DataRow is not in the current DataRowCollection when tried move item from DataGridView to another

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two DataGridView like this:

[image]

Button selected will move DataRow of DataGridView to another DataGridView.

My code like this:

```
public static DataRow[] GetSelectedDataRows(DataGridView grid)
{
    DataRow[] dRows = new DataRow[grid.SelectedRows.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
        dRows[i] = ((DataRowView)grid.SelectedRows[i].DataBoundItem).Row;

    return dRows;
}

public void MoveRows(DataTable src, DataTable dest, DataRow[] rows)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in rows)
    {
        // add to dest
        dest.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);

        // remove from src
        src.Rows.Remove(row);
    }
}
```

I use it in Event `btnMoveToRight_Click()`.

`MoveRows(dtUser, dtUserStop, GetSelectedDataRows(dgvUser));`

It throws exception error like:

> The given DataRow is not in the current DataRowCollection

at line:

`src.Rows.Remove(row);`

Comment: Avoid dealing with `DataRow` objects.  Instead, use the destination table's `NewRow()` method, loop over the columns copying values, and then add the new row to the destination table.  Remove the source row when that is done.  `DataRow` objects are linked to their respective tables, and those associations can be bothersome.  I.e. don't "move rows", move data as new rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the `Table` field of a `DataRow`.

So you need to **create a new** row and also **copy the data** separately, maybe like this:

```
public void MoveRows(DataTable src, DataTable dest, DataRow[] rows)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in rows)
    {
        // create empty row
        DataRow newrow = dest.NewRow();
        // copy data
        newrow.ItemArray = row.ItemArray;
        // add to dest
        dest.Rows.Add(newrow);  // (*)

        // remove from src NOTE: This may or may not throw an RowNotInTableException
        // to avoid it you can skip the Remove and use the loop below instead..
        src.Rows.Remove(row);
    }
    // alternative way of removing the rows..
    //foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dgvUser.SelectedRows)
    //{
    //    dgvUser.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
    //}

}
```

(*) An even shorter way to clone a `DataRow` is using this overload of the Add method:

```
  dest.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
```

No need for the `newrow` now. **Note** that you may want to copy the `RowState` from the old to the new row!? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318631/datatable-rowstate-always-in-added-state/37394187?s=1|4.1687#37394187) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34825334/drag-and-drop-row-in-a-datagridview/34826867?s=2|0.1403#34826867) for examples of changing the [RowState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you find you need to remove the `DataRows` via removing the `DataGridViewRows` you should add the DGV to the parameters of the `MoveRows` function to avoid an unecessary dependence..!

Of course this assumes that the `DataTables` have the same structure, maybe because one is a (structural) clone of the other:

```
  dest = src.Clone();
```

Comment: I updated my code like your answer. But I can remove `row` at line: `src.Rows.Remove(row);`. Still error: `The given DataRow is not in the current DataRowCollection`.

Comment: Whoops I made a typo when copying. Of course we need to add the __new__ row, that's why we created it.. See the updated answer..

Comment: It's also an error at `src.Rows.Remove(row);` with same error. I don't know this error still loop. I changed my code like your answer.

Comment: So you now have `dest.Rows.Add(newrow.ItemArray);` nor  `dest.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);` ??

Comment: Yes, I changed `row.ItemArray` to `newrow.ItemArray`. It's still not working.

Comment: Damn, there was another typo (*), but it could not have lead to that error message.. In fact it works even with the 'wrong' version. (There are two overloads of the Add method we can both use..) Other than that the code, together with your other function, works fine here and moves selected rows form one dgv/table to another. Make sure you didn't mix up the DGVs..

Comment: I updated the link to gif because size gif too larger, I can't create full gif file. At this time, it a success. So, you can see gif bellow when I tried to debug. It can be easy to know my problem. I checked two DGVs with the same struct. I don't mix up anything from DGVs. Can you see gif image when I debug and have error at here (time of gif about 52s): http://imgur.com/a/MQ12Y

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118052/discussion-between-taw-and-vn-lc).

Answer (score 0):

`DataRow` has a `DataTable` property on it (`DataRow.Table`).

This leads me to think that adding the row to a new table breaks the association with the old `DataTable`, so you don't need to call `src.Rows.Remove(row)`.

Comment: If I do not call `src.Rows.Remove(row)`, it like copies rows from DataGridView to another. I want to delete this after added success.